# Oracle FORMS 12C - Generate password protected file from oracle forms application with CLIENT_TEXT_IO webutil

Tags: oracle, zip, password-protection, oracleforms

We have an application in Oracle forms. From a form, we generate a .TXT file with some data. Now we are looking for options to generate a password protected file (preferrably zip file as .TXT cannot be password protected directly)
We use CLIENT_TEXT_IO to write data into file and close.

Is it possible to generate password protected zip file with CLIENT_TEXT_IO webutil?

```
U_IN_FILE := CLIENT_TEXT_IO.FOPEN (:M_FILE_PATH || 'some data.TXT','w');
CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE(U_IN_FILE,'some data');
CLIENT_TEXT_IO.FCLOSE (U_IN_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you'd do that in two steps:

- create .txt file the way you're already doing it
- use `CLIENT_HOST` to invoke command-line ZIP utility and create a password-protected ZIP file

For example, on my MS Windows, using 7-zip, it would look like this:

```
c:\Temp\ZIP>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a zipped_file.7z test.txt -pMARCH18

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 66 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: zipped_file.7z

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 66 bytes (1 KiB)


Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 202 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

c:\Temp\ZIP>
```

ZIP command itself, explained:

```
7z a zipped_file.7z test.txt -pMARCH18
```

- `7z` - invokes the utility
- `a` - add to archive
- `zipped_file.7z` - ZIP file name
- `test.txt` - this is the file I'm going to ZIP
- `-pMARCH18` - password is `MARCH18`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the same with Winzip and it gives me 100501: non-Oracle Exception. Form is compiling fine. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: CLIENT_HOST('cmd /c cd C:\Program Files\WinZip winzip64 a '||:M_FILE_PATH||'\ACH_'||:GLOBAL.COMP_CTRY_ISO_CODE||'_'||M_C2.M_BATCH_REF_NUMBER||'.zip '||:M_FILE_PATH||'\PP_'||:GLOBAL.COMP_CTRY_ISO_CODE||'_'||M_C2.M_BATCH_REF_NUMBER||'.TXT -pMARCH2021',NO_SCREEN);

Comment: As it says, error is external to Oracle. Did you check whether your WINZIP command works properly? Don't run it immediately (with CLIENT_HOST) - prepare it into a local variable and display it on the screen, then copy/paste it into operating system command prompt window and execute it; see what happens.

Comment: Also, check whether you're using WHEN OTHERS exception handler in your procedure. If so, remove it; once I got the same 100501 error which was fixed by removing that exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error calling Winzip, refer to these MyOracleSupport Notes:

1568659.1
1547133.1

In short, you will need to escape some of the characters in your call.